# How to extract the words inside the 2nd brackets using Regexp_extract in Bigquery?

Tags: google-bigquery, re2

I am having a **textPayload** column in **bigquery** table containing these values

**textPayload**

```
# User@Host: root[root] @  [44.27.156.25]  thread_id: 67301  server_id: 1220687984
```

I need to extract the username and host name as separate fields in the following fashion:

**User**:root **Host**:44.27.156.25,

All the values of this column will be containing the text as posted above

I am trying like this `Select Regexp_Extract(textPayload,` -> unable to get the Regex

I am new to regexp_extract and I am not able to extract the 2nd word which is the **host:44.27.156.25**,

Can anyone help me in extracting the Host name through a Regexp_extract ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the context of `User@` in the text payload, and that you want an IP address in square brackets, to find the content you want:

```sql
SELECT
    textPayload,
    REGEXP_EXTRACT(textPayload, r"\bUser@.*?\[(.*?)\]") AS User,
    REGEXP_EXTRACT(textPayload, r"\[(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)\]"
FROM yourTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [regexp_extract_all](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#regexp_extract_all) with `r'\[(.+?)\]'`:

```
select regexp_extract_all('# User@Host: root[root] @  [44.27.156.25]  thread_id: 67301  server_id: 1220687984', r'\[(.+?)\]')
```

[image]